# What is the simplest algorithm for mesh generation of an arbitrary quadrilateral?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, direct3d, mesh

What is the simplest algorithm for decomposing a quadrilateral into an arbitrary number of triangles?

Comment: What's the "mesg" tag supposed to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably midpoint triangle subdivision.  Cut your quad into two triangles, then use the midpoints of each triangle edge as vertexes for four new triangles.

Comment: A very simple and easy to implement tesselation system.  Easy to do an arbitrary number of trinagles too.  Keep subdividing until you have "n" triangles.